# Faster k-shortest path algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, pathfinding

In the \$k\$-shortest path problem, we are searching for (at most) \$k\$ distinct, shortest paths connecting two given terminal nodes. You can see the previous version [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116292/k-shortest-path-algorithm-in-java). This implementation, however, represents the intermediate paths in the open list as linked lists so that extending such a path by one node runs in \$\Theta(1)\$ time. My code is below:

**`net.coderodde.graph.kshortest.impl.FasterDefaultShortestPathFinder`**

```
package net.coderodde.graph.kshortest.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;
import net.coderodde.graph.DirectedGraphNode;
import net.coderodde.graph.DirectedGraphWeightFunction;
import net.coderodde.graph.kshortest.AbstractKShortestPathFinder;
import net.coderodde.graph.kshortest.Path;

/**
 * This class implements a rather simple k-shortest path algorithm from
 * <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing#Algorithm">
 * Wikipedia
 * </a>. This version improves 
 * {@link net.coderodde.graph.kshortest.impl.DefaultKShortestPathFinder} via 
 * using linked lists of nodes as the paths.
 *
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jun 4, 2019)
 */
public class FasterDefaultKShortestPathFinder 
        extends AbstractKShortestPathFinder {

    @Override
    public List<Path>
         findShortestPaths(DirectedGraphNode source, 
                           DirectedGraphNode target,
                           DirectedGraphWeightFunction weightFunction, 
                           int k) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(source, "The source node is null.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(target, "The target node is null.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(weightFunction,
                               "The weight function is null.");
        checkK(k);

        List<LinkedPathNode> linkedPathTails = new ArrayList<>(k);
        Map<DirectedGraphNode, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();
        Queue<LinkedPathNode> HEAP = new PriorityQueue<>();

        HEAP.add(new LinkedPathNode(weightFunction, source));

        while (!HEAP.isEmpty() && countMap.getOrDefault(target, 0) < k) {
            LinkedPathNode currentPath = HEAP.remove();
            DirectedGraphNode endNode = currentPath.getTailNode();
            countMap.put(endNode, countMap.getOrDefault(endNode, 0) + 1);

            if (endNode.equals(target)) {
                linkedPathTails.add(currentPath);
            }

            if (countMap.get(endNode) <= k) {
                for (DirectedGraphNode child : endNode.children()) {
                    HEAP.add(currentPath.append(child));
                }
            }
        }

        return convertListOfLinkedPathsToPaths(linkedPathTails);
    }

    private static final List<Path> 
        convertListOfLinkedPathsToPaths(
                List<LinkedPathNode> linkedPathTails) {
        List<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>(linkedPathTails.size());

        for (LinkedPathNode linkedPathNode : linkedPathTails) {
            paths.add(linkedPathNode.toPath());
        }

        return paths;
    }
}
```

**`net.coderodde.graph.kshortest.impl.LinkedPathNode`**

```
package net.coderodde.graph.kshortest.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import net.coderodde.graph.DirectedGraphWeightFunction;
import java.util.Objects;
import net.coderodde.graph.DirectedGraphNode;
import net.coderodde.graph.kshortest.Path;

/**
 * This class represents a path in a graph. The only difference between 
 * {@link net.coderodde.graph.kshortest.Path} is that this class implements the
 * path as a linked list of graph nodes. This arrangement allows us to extend 
 * any given path by one graph node in constant time.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jun 4, 2019)
 */
final class LinkedPathNode implements Comparable<LinkedPathNode> {

    private final DirectedGraphWeightFunction weightFunction;
    private final DirectedGraphNode node;
    private final LinkedPathNode previousLinkedPathNode;
    private double totalCost;

    public LinkedPathNode(DirectedGraphWeightFunction weightFunction,
                   DirectedGraphNode node) {
        this.weightFunction =
                Objects.requireNonNull(
                        weightFunction,
                        "The input weight function is null.");

        this.node = Objects.requireNonNull(node, "The input node is null.");
        this.totalCost = 0.0;
        this.previousLinkedPathNode = null;
    }

    LinkedPathNode(LinkedPathNode path, DirectedGraphNode node) {
        this.weightFunction = path.weightFunction;
        this.node = node;
        this.previousLinkedPathNode = path;
        this.totalCost += weightFunction.get(previousLinkedPathNode.node, node);
    }

    LinkedPathNode append(DirectedGraphNode node) {
        return new LinkedPathNode(this, node);
    }

    LinkedPathNode getPreviousLinkedPathNode() {
        return this.previousLinkedPathNode;
    }

    DirectedGraphNode getTailNode() {
        return this.node;
    }

    Path toPath() {
        List<DirectedGraphNode> path = new ArrayList<>();
        LinkedPathNode node = this;

        while (node != null) {
            path.add(node.node);
            node = node.previousLinkedPathNode;
        }

        Collections.<DirectedGraphNode>reverse(path);
        return new Path(path, this.weightFunction);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(LinkedPathNode o) {
        return Double.compare(totalCost, o.totalCost);
    }
}
```

**Critique request**

I would love to hear comments about naming conventions, maintainability and readability, but please tell me anything that comes to mind.

**Miscellany**

See [this project](https://github.com/coderodde/KShortestPathAlgorithms/tree/03571b39803a8d6e4f54c84f92efb461960da2c4) for all the missing Java files.